# What would you say the sub problem is in this dynamic programming challenge?

Tags: algorithms

Alongside the OBJ files for each figurine, Nintendo has released the following information about each figurine f:
• the filament cost (amount of filament necessary) to print f, denoted fc, in grams, as an integer
• the amount that Nintendo will pay for each printed copy of f, denoted fp

Find P(N), the maximum profit which can be attained with N grams of filament by printing figurines, selling filament, or some combination thereof. Don’t forget base cases!

Comment: Please don't just dump your problem here. Prove that you have tried to solve it yourself and asked a detailled question about where you were stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like homework :( what have you tried?

In any case, take the following hint: If you use the first figurine exactly $k$ times, you lost $k\cdot fc_1$ grams of filament, but you win $k \cdot fp_1$. Now that you have decided to use the first figurine $k$ times, how does the rest of the problem looks like?

Comment: Though it may be usefull, this looks like a comment more than an answer.